# MomentJS toISOString with local timezone

Tags: momentjs

I've been using `toISOString` to serialize momentJS date before sending to the server via jQuery. It works fine for me except it converts date to UTC but I need to keep the local timezone. Does momentJS have a method for this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can either call `.format()` without any parameters, or you can call `.toISOString(true)`.  Both are in ISO 8601 extended format, the difference is only in whether milliseconds are included or not.

```js
// get the current moment, in local mode
const m = moment();

// format without parameters will give the ISO string including offset
console.log(`moment().format() === "${ m.format() }"`);

// if you want to include milliseconds, you can use toISOString(true) instead
console.log(`moment().toISOString(true) === "${ m.toISOString(true) }"`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It does not give the ISO format

Comment: @Taosif7 - yes, it does.  This is a very old answer, but I updated it just now to include a working code snippet that demonstrates both `format()` and `toISOString(true)`.

Answer (score 22):

Added in 2.20.0:

```
moment().toISOString(true)
```

Output:

```
"2018-05-13T16:16:13.507+03:00"
```

Found answer [here](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1751).

[Documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/).